# a bitwise expression that returns 1 when mask is all zeros and x when mask is all ones

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Let's say we have a `mask` variable that can either be `0` (all zoers) or `-1` (all ones).

I have another variable `x` which is let's say `42`.

What (possibly) is the bitwise expression that results in:

- `1` when `mask == 0`
- `x` when `mask == -1`

what I'm trying to do is explore ways to eliminate the following `if` statement

```c
unsigned x = 3;
unsigned some_number = 42;

// ~~~

if (some_number % x == 0)
{
    some_number /= x;
}
```

Regarding the **type** of variables in the particular problem that I'm working on (look below), all of the numbers are unsigned integers for example `unsigned`.

---

**EDIT 2 (MISTAKE)**: I made a **mistake** and forgot that mask is either `0` (**all zeros**) or, `-1` (**all ones**) which I previously said `1` (only whose least significant bit is one). *Please accept my apologies as I wasted your precious time*.

---

**EDIT 1:**

Overall the point is **not** to use `if-else` constructs (including the conditional operator (`?:`)). Instead I'm looking for bit manipulations similar to those which is used in **branchless** practices. This question isn't whether it is going to be more performant or not in this case, or whether the answer could be considered a good practice or not. It's just to explore the world of bit manipulation.

---

Here is my try

```c
// Check whether some_number is divisible by x
unsigned mask = ((some_number % x) - 1) >> 31;
unsigned deonm = // ??
some_number =/ denom
```

I'm using this to answer project Euler's *third* question and here's the code

```c
size_t largest_prime_factor(size_t number)
{
    if (number < 2) return 0;
    if (number == 2) return 2;
    while ((number & 1) == 0)
    {
        number >>= 1;
    }
    size_t lpf = 2;
    size_t i = 3;
    size_t max_iter = sqrt(number);
    while (i < max_iter)
    {
        size_t mask = ((number % i) - 1) >> 31;
        lpf = (i & mask) | (lpf & ~mask);
        number /= X; // mask = 0 => X=1; mask = 1 => X=i
        i += 2;
    }
    return lpf;
}
```

---

NOTE: Please, if possible, suggest a better title.

Comment: What type is `x`? Answers might differ depending on whether `x` is an integer of various widths, whether that type is specifically known, or whether `x` is has a floating-point type or some other type.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to accomplish with this? Are you trying "optimize" your code better than what your compiler is already doing?

Comment: @EricPostpischil all variables are integers

Comment: @Ali: “integers” is not a type in C. Types are `bool`, `char`, `signed char`, `int`, `long int`, `float`, `double`, and so on. Several of the types are integer types, but “integer” is insufficient to specify which one. What type is `x`?

Comment: @Brian61354270 I am learning bit-wise operation and exploring branchless programming. I'm not sure this leads to optimization. I understand that compiler most likely optimize 99% of what I do in C. But I see it as a practice and nothing more.

Comment: @EricPostpischil To be more precise all variables are `int`.

Comment: Specify the operators allowed. Technically a bitwise operator is one in which each bit of the result is dependent on the corresponding bit(s) of the operand(s), so there is no way for a high bit of the result to depend on a low bit of `mask` using only bitwise operators. If one admits shifts as bitwise operators, a solution can be constructed from multiple shifts, but this will involve multiple shifts, so it will be inefficient. Sometimes requests for “bitwise operators” are actually meant to include `!`, from which a short solution can be constructed.

Comment: `- (unsigned) mask & x` produces the bits of `x` if `mask` is 1 and 0 if `mask` is 0. So `(- (unsigned) mask & x) | !mask` produces either the bits of `x` or 1, correspondingly. However, then we have an `unsigned` type, and converting that to `int` is awkward in C, because conversion of out-of-range integer values to a signed integer type is implementation-defined. Alternately, `(-mask & x) | !mask` will work in C implementations that use two’s complement (all normal modern ones) and does not require type conversion. (Note these use `-`, which is not a bitwise operator.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil You may want to use all of the bitwise operators in C. `>>`, `<<`, `|`, `&`, `^`, `~`.

Comment: I'm not sure about your `mask` variable - are you sure that it is either 0 or 1? `some_number % x` can return any value from 0 to x-1 as result of reminder

Comment: @IłyaBursov: They have `some_number % x == 0`.

Comment: How would an expression such as you describe enable you to eliminate the `if` statement?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I suppose OP wants something like `some_number /= SOMETHING(x, some_number%x == 0);`

Comment: Perhaps, @IłyaBursov, but I'm not prepared to put words in their mouth.  On the other hand, if they do have something like that in mind then I intend to draw attention to how godawful the resulting expression would be.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ok, now that I saw the answers I should say: in terms of operators, you can use any operator except those that is equivalent to if and else, for example: the ternary operator of `?:`. Maybe arithmetic operators here and there, but I think the answer will highly contain mostly bitwise operators.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I should've mentioned that in this particular problem that I'm working on, all the integers are `unsigned`. But one could extend the problem to signed integers. Thank you for your addressing the information on C standard, it's always good (at least to me and for my understanding) to know these small details.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I understand your point. I just asked question because I don't have a lot of information on bit-manipulation and branchless computing. I'm just at the beginning. Thus, I don't know how complicated it would be. This question will inherently won't have any benefit in terms of performance or good practice. To me, I think it's just to know how one come up with an answer to this question and I understand that not many people care about these stuff.

Comment: @IłyaBursov here is the expression whose result is assigned to `mask`: `unsigned mask = ((some_number % x) - 1) >> 31;` It basically checks whether `some_number` is divisible by `x`.

Comment: @Ali: better for "0 if `i` evenly divides `number`, or 1 if it does not" would be `!!(number % i)`.

Comment: It's not just the answerers time you wasted, it's also us observers who have to sort through the answers to figure out if they applied to the original question or the updated one.  Apology NOT accepted.

Comment: @MarkRansom For the record: The answers provide **Ted Lyngmo** and **nneonneo** are written before my modification to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume the mask (which I'll call `m`), `x`, and the result (which I'll call `r`) are unsigned integer types of the same size. I shall call that type `TYPE`.

---

For most of the bits, it's easy: r<sub>i</sub> = x<sub>i</sub> & m<sub>i</sub>

The least significant bit (r<sub>0</sub>) is different, though. The following shows the desired value for r<sub>0</sub> based on the values of m<sub>0</sub> and x<sub>0</sub>:

| r<sub>0</sub> | m<sub>0</sub> = 0 | m<sub>0</sub> = 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x<sub>0</sub> = 0 | 1 | 0 |
| x<sub>0</sub> = 1 | 1 | 1 |

So we get r<sub>0</sub> = ~m<sub>0</sub> | x<sub>0</sub>

Now, we just need to combine them.

We want to apply the first rule to all the bits but the last. This can be done by using a mask that lets through all bits but the last (`... & ( ~(TYPE)1 )`).

We want to apply the second rule for just the last bit. This can be done by using a mask that lets through only the last bit (`... & 1`).

All together:

```c
r = ( x & m & ( ~(TYPE)1 ) ) | ( ( ~m | x ) & 1 );
```

And now we have a solution with just bit operations (and a cast which can maybe be avoided by using the correct numeric literal suffix).

Comment: I tested it and surely this is the correct answer. I changed all unsigned types to signed types (+ changing TYPE to corresponding signed type) and the code worked as well because I think all of the numbers in the problem are positive integers. -- I will dig into it and write down my thoughts to get it better as I can't understand it by just reading it.

Comment: I can add some details. Gimme a sec

Comment: OK. If not out of context, could you also explain what role the `TYPE` plays generally in bit-masking? Why are you considering it in your answer?

Comment: Well, you want `...1111110` since the rule applies to all but the last bit. So you want something like `~1`. The type cast gets the right number of "ones".

Comment: Re "*I changed all unsigned types to signed types*", Doesn't really make sense to do bit operations on signed types. So I don't. Doesn't mean you can't cast the inputs from signed types and cast the result back to signed.

Comment: Now I get why you use `TYPE`. Very enthralling idea. About the signed cast, I forgot about this point as for example a left shift can screw things up. that was a mistake on my part. It doesn't indeed make sense. _Now I have a better understanding on this topic. Thank you for your explanations_.

Comment: With unsigned types, you could use `( x & m ) >> 1 << 1` instead of `x & m & ( ~(TYPE)1 )`

Answer (score 3):

In your particular case, you may *not* want to avoid the branch: divisions can be expensive, while a correctly predicted branch can be cheap. If the branch is not taken frequently (e.g. brute-force factoring), the result will be faster than trying to always divide by a computed divisor.

If you just want a branchless solution:

```
(x - 1) * mask + 1
```

works, but won't necessarily be faster due to the multiply. Alternatively, if `mask` is unsigned, you could use `((x - 1) & -mask) + 1` which is probably slightly faster.

You can also parallelize this a bit to reduce the dependency chain: `(x & -mask) + !mask`.

Answer (score 2):

For the case where `mask` can be either `0` or `1`

```c
1 - mask  // or !mask => 1 when mask is 0
+         // or |
x * mask  //          => x when mask is 1
```

Answer (score 1):

With xor, you can get a shorter solution:

```
 ((x ^ 1) & mask) ^ 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit and operation does almost produce the desired output:

- if your unsigned mask is all ones `-1U` then `mask & x == x`
- if your unsigned mask is all zeros `0U` then `mask & x == 0`

We see that we can complement with another operation:

- if your unsigned mask is all ones `-1U` then `mask + 1 == 0`
- if your unsigned mask is all zeros `0U` then `mask + 1 == 1`

By summing up the two expressions `mask + 1 + (mask & x)` you get what you want:

- `1` when `mask == 0U`
- `x`when `mask == -1U`